# API call limited to 500 results - how to iterate through to get all results?

Tags: php, json, api

I am developing a web app which iterates through API results to insert into a MySQL database.

The API I am using limits records returned to a maximum of 500 per call.

They have a parameter where you can choose which "page" to return results from, so for 1504 (current number of records) records, I could call page 2 and return results from 500-999.

I am semi novice at best, and this is my first foray into working with APIs...I am struggling to get my head around how I could gather all 1504 results.

The API documentation for this is: https://developer.trademe.co.nz/api-reference/search-methods/rental-search/

I can use the "page" parameter to choose which page of results I want.

```
$url = "https://api.tmsandbox.co.nz/v1/Search/Property/Rental.json";

$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxx", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT", oauth_signature="xxx"';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
$pageSize = 10;
$data = array(
    "rows" => $pageSize,
    "sort_order" => "ExpiryDesc",
    "page" => 1
);
$totalPages = PHP_INT_MAX;
$result = [];
do {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?".http_build_query ($data));
    $resulta = curl_exec($curl);

    $array = json_decode($resulta, true);
    array_merge($result, $array);
    $data['page']++;
    if ( $totalPages == PHP_INT_MAX )   {
        $totalPages = floor($array['TotalCount']/$pageSize);
    }

}
while ( $totalPages < $data['page']);

$properties = $array['List'];
$prop_count = $array['TotalCount'];
curl_close($curl);
```

This is the code I am using to return the 500 results. $prop_count holds the total number of rows (1504) and $pages holds the number of pages (in this case, 3.08).

Can anyone please give me a head start on the logical order to implement some kind of loop to return all results? I'm sitting here and racking my brain trying to get started.

Comment: The number you've fetch is `$currentPage * $countPerPage`.  If that's less than `$totalCount`, keep going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not able to test this, the principle here is to keep on making requests until there are no more pages.  The first time round the loop it will work out the number of pages(using TotalCount from the returned content / pageSize - using `floor()` so that 3.1 becomes 3).  Then at the end of the loop it checks if the current page is > total pages.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 120);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
$pageSize = 500;
$data = array(
    "rows" => $pageSize,
    "sort_order" => "ExpiryDesc",
    "page" => 1
);
$totalPages = PHP_INT_MAX;
$result = [];
do {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url."?".http_build_query ($data));
    $resulta = curl_exec($curl);

    $array = json_decode($resulta, true);
    $result[] = $array['List'];
    $data['page']++;
    if ( $totalPages == PHP_INT_MAX )   {
        $totalPages = floor($array['TotalCount']/$pageSize);
    }

}
while ( $totalPages > $data['page']);
curl_close($curl);

// Loop through the pages of results and in each page each listing
foreach ( $result as $page )    {
    foreach ( $page as $item ){
        // Process each item
        echo $item['ListingId'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the look of this Nigel, however when I run the test it filled my error log up to 1.2GB size. Normally that's how I "fudge" my way through fixing things. I know it must be hard from your end unable to test the code, but can you see anything that might cause this?

Comment: `curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given` is the error it's giving me. I added back in the $url variable as that has the API url in, but not quite sure how to structure the $query_url variable in this new format? I tried just using my old format but that still throws up the same error.

Comment: I've just corrected the two lines `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL...` and `$resulta = curl_exec($curl);`

Comment: no more 1.2GB error files! Although I am getting a timeout (currently set at 300 seconds), which I don't think should be happening on 1500 records? 500 using my old method took about 8 seconds? I appreciate all your help!

Comment: Am I right in saying that when an API refers to "request limiting", it means the number of times you call the API, and not the records returned? Second time today I have been locked out, because they say I've exceeded the 1000 calls per hour limit. I would assume, with this code, it would only make 3 calls?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have it semi working! I had to remove the index number from array, because for some reason it was no longer needed. One final question, the array does not seem to be merging? For testing purposes, I have set the page size to 10, and I break out of the while loop after 3 pages. I only get the first 10 results returned, not 30? I have updated my original post with the current code I'm using. Any final words of wisdom?

Comment: Can you try and replace the line `array_merge($result, $array);` with `$result[] = $array;`, you may find they have string keys which will overwrite each other.  You will need to loop over the different arrays though as it will be an array of arrays (use `print_r($result);` after the loop to check.

Comment: Appreciate all your help Nigel - I think I'm going to have to hire a developer as I can't figure it out. I replaced the `array_merge($result, $array);` with `$result[] = $array;` and it still only returns the first set and I can't figure out looping through the different arrays. Thanks for all your efforts :-)

Comment: If you want to send me the login details, I'm happy to try it. (You can put them in a comment and delete the comment once I have them) - don't have to do this if you don't want to, but happy to help.

Comment: Wow, that's a terrific offer, thank you very much - trouble is I only have it running on my local server - I can put up my code with the API keys, if you have an environment you can run the script in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187633/discussion-between-nigel-ren-and-jamie-sutton).

Comment: If this is sorted - can you mark it as answered, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use loop and send again the request.

```
    for($i=1;$i<4;$i++)
        request(rows=$i*500);
```

Rows will be like this

```
i=1, rows=500
i=2, rows=1000
i=3, rows=1500
i=4, rows=2000
```